# Are there release notes for ADFv2?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I noticed new options in an existing pipeline I built which got me wondering what it was and what else was added that I didn't notice.  Most other services have release notes, surely this exists for ADFv2?  How do I get on the list?

Comment: What new options?

Comment: Inside of a blob storage connection there are options now to "filter by last modified" that weren't there a few days earlier.  Not a major thing obviously but still curious to know what else is new that I am not seeing immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the ADF V2 release notes from the ADF portal https://adf.azure.com/datafactories

at the top right part of the page.
[sample release note screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq9vo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing to a patch notes we have is the roadmap: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?tag=data-factory

Hope this helped!